# Datatable error on initialising via node require

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatable

the code am using to require the datatables plugins is

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

dt = require('datatables.net')(window, $);
dt_bs = require('datatables.net-bs')(window, $);
buttons = require('datatables.net-buttons')(window, $);
buttons_bs = require('datatables.net-buttons-bs')(window, $);
responsive = require('datatables.net-responsive')(window, $);
responsive_bs = require('datatables.net-responsive-bs')(window, $);
colreorder = require('datatables.net-colreorder')(window, $);
fixedheader = require('datatables.net-fixedheader')(window, $);
scroller = require('datatables.net-scroller')(window, $);
```

but when I compile the assets and run the error am getting is

```
TypeError: this is undefined
```

I don't know what am doing wrong and yes I have tested the error comes from this section because if I comment out the section there is no error so any help would be highly appreciated, it's already driving me nuts. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** [This](https://datatables.net/download/npm) is my reference

Comment: Is this code running in a browser?

Comment: am gulping the js file before running it in a browser

Comment: Where is the error coming from?

Comment: I have no clue but when I comment out the datatable plugins (all of them), the error is gone and when I require the plugins (any of them),  the error reappears

Comment: Try one at a time? --- Are you sure the error doesn't say which file it's coming from?

Comment: you see am using gulp to combine everything into one js file which is the one am importing to browser

Comment: Yes. Can you try commenting out all of the dependencies, and re-include them one at a time?

Comment: thats what am trying right now, will update you in a bit

Comment: tried uncommenting one require  at a time, but same issue with all packages @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my code to this and the error disappeared

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

dt = require('datatables.net');
dt_bs = require('datatables.net-bs');
buttons = require('datatables.net-buttons');
buttons_bs = require('datatables.net-buttons-bs');
responsive = require('datatables.net-responsive');
responsive_bs = require('datatables.net-responsive-bs');
colreorder = require('datatables.net-colreorder');
fixedheader = require('datatables.net-fixedheader');
scroller = require('datatables.net-scroller');
```